# What is the meaning of "revenue release" in a software package description? legal implications?

Tags: software, licensing

When trying to develop JavaCard with a current Java Card Development kit, the respective Oracle download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-classic-3_0_4-rr-bin-do has a threatening name addition to the newest JavaCard packages:

These are marked "**Revenue Release**".

What does that mean?

Do you have to share a fixed or relative part of your revenue? Is there some other indirect meaning or legal implication to this?

I couldn't find anything on this term by a web search or in the license terms, but then, IANAL. So I am asking here.

Does the term "revenue release" have a common or specific legal meaning?

Comment: I don't think it's a legal term at all, just Oracle's designation for that particular version ("release" = "version") of the software.  I've seen "revenue" used as an adjective in business jargon to refer to the "official" version of a product, the one that is actually sold to customers, distinguishing it from internal or test versions.  For example, in airline lingo, a "revenue flight" is one which actually carries paying passengers, as opposed to a test flight, or a repositioning flight which moves an empty airplane to where it's needed.

Comment: I didn't find any other software company who ever labelled their release "revenue". Nor did Oracle before. What is different in this instance?

Comment: @NateEldredge This sounds like a solid answer to the question.

Comment: @ohwilleke: Well, I'm not positive about it, and if I'm right it probably means the question is actually off topic.

Comment: I asked at stackoverflow before, was told this was off topic and a legal question about licensing. If this isn't the right stackexchange to ask about licenses, in which should I ask?